# How to get the log of all the mercurial changesets affecting files in a certain folder from a certain changeset up?

Tags: mercurial

I have `$HG_NODE` referencing the changeset from which I wish to start:

```
[vcs@Quake /tmp/test/advanced]$ hg log -r $HG_NODE: --template '{node|short}:{files}\n'
c5eefea063fd:1.txt backup.cmd notes.txt
370f9ef91471:1.txt backup.cmd notes.txt
5eac12f79df6:advanced/Program.cs advanced/a advanced/b advanced/notes.txt lab6/scratch2/Fiobonacci.sln lab6/scratch2/Program.cs lab6/scratch2/xxx lab6/scratch2/yyy
4be96f43f327:advanced/1.txt
c724950dd2a6:advanced/Fiobonacci.csproj advanced/aaa.kuku
```

Now, I also have a directory, which is of a particular interest to me. So, I wish to get all the changesets from the starting one affecting the files in this directory.

First, I tried to check if I can get it for a specific file:

```
[vcs@Quake /tmp/test/advanced]$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('path:advanced/1.txt')" --template '{node|short}\n'
4be96f43f327
```

Then, for all the files in that directory. But I seem to be missing something:

```
[vcs@Quake /tmp/test/advanced]$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('path:advanced/**')" --template '{node|short}\n'
[vcs@Quake /tmp/test/advanced]$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('set:advanced/**')" --template '{node|short}\n'
abort: fileset expression with no context
[vcs@Quake /tmp/test/advanced]$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('glob:advanced/**')" --template '{node|short}\n'
[vcs@Quake /tmp/test/advanced]$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('advanced/**')" --template '{node|short}\n'
[vcs@Quake /tmp/test/advanced]$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('re:^advanced/.*')" --template '{node|short}\n'
5eac12f79df6
4be96f43f327
c724950dd2a6
```

Only the `re:` prefix works for me, but this is something that should work with `glob:` as well.

How can I make it work with `glob:` and `**` ?

Comment: Not an answer, but your `glob` suggestion works for me (my test repo has a subdir called `dd`): `hg log --style compact -r "0: and file('glob:dd/**')"`. Note that I'm using Windows, and not using an environment variable to reference the first node, tho'.

Comment: Likewise, the following works when I have `%HGN` set (yes, still using Windows): `hg log -r "%HGN%: and file('glob:dd/**')" --template {node^|short}\n`

Comment: A quick test suggests it's failing because you are already in the `advanced` directory. If you replace the `glob:advanced/**` with `glob:**` does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little playing, I think it's because you are already in the `advanced` directory.  Try one of the following options (assuming this is the case):

1) Specify only that you want to match the files in this directory:

```
$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('glob:**')" --template '{node|short}\n'
5eac12f79df6
4be96f43f327
c724950dd2a6
```

2) Go to the parent directory:

```
$ cd ..
$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('glob:advanced/**')" --template '{node|short}\n'
5eac12f79df6
4be96f43f327
c724950dd2a6
```

3) Use the `path` option, but don't specify the `/**`:

```
$ hg log -r "$HG_NODE: and file('path:advanced')" --template '{node|short}\n'
5eac12f79df6
4be96f43f327
c724950dd2a6
```

These options all seem to work in my small test repo.